# change password for current user in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest me how to change password for current user,having user_id,email and username in javascript.
when i am going to change password it showing me error: User already exist.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too vague to be answered. You should post some code and explain you problem more thoroughly.

Comment: i have created username,email,password when i cick on save button after completing the field.It stored in Auth0.

Comment: so here i want to change password for existing user.when i click on save button it showing error as user already exist.

Comment: Are you storing the details in a database, or...? Please [edit] the question to show the relevant code.

Comment: I am storing my information in auth0.

Comment: @poornima If you say you are storing your information in auth0. How everyone will come to know what is auth0 and how you are trying to do it. Please post your code snippet here or create a fiddle with what you have done so far, so that people here can review it and will try to help you.